# For what $x$ does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}{\cos{(n\cdot x)}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have no clue of what I should try first. Any help is welcome! Thanks

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}{\cos{(n\cdot x)}}$$

Here's my attempt to fix the above:

(1) I started using with the Limit Comparison Test:$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}{\cos{(n\cdot x)}}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ with If the limit of $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is positive, then the sum of ${a_n}$ converges if and only if the sum of b[n] converges. If the limit of $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is zero, and the sum of ${b_n}$ converges, then the sum of ${a_n}$ also converges.

(2) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ converges because of the ratio test.

(3) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}{\cos{(n\cdot x)}}$ converges according to the limit comparison test.

(4)Knowing that the series converges, we calculate its infinite sum that equals to: Re(x) according to WolframAlpha.

(5) In conclusion, to make series converge the values of $x$ are $Re(x)$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Please provide [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) and avoid ["no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: A useful tool here is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Comment: Rob, I appreciate the comment I will keep in mind your suggestions to improve my questions in the future, best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: a series converges (conditionally) if it converges absolutely.

Hint 2: $|\frac{\cos(nx)}{2^n}|\leq \frac{1}{2^n}$

Comment: Please do not answer questions that do not meet the [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). The moderators may suspend your account.

Comment: @Gary it's my first question, please be kind. I promise to make it better in the future.

Comment: @FedericoArielAguirre do not worry, and please don't be scared away by the rather mean welcome. However, you can practice making your questions better by editing this one, and using some of the techniques in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933 e.g. you can write out the definitions of convergence, and absolute convergence, and the geometric series. You might even get your question un-closed! Practicing with this one will be sure to make your future questions met with more enthusiasm :-)